# Prevent DataList to Refesh for ClickEvents

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, datalist

I have a `DataList` Control with `HeaderTemplate` as `LinkButton`s.

**The markup is**

```
 <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlYears"  OnItemDataBound="dlYears_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lblYear1" runat="server" OnClick="Year_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lblYear2" runat="server" OnClick="Year_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server"Text='<%# String.Format("{0:f2}",DataBinder.Eval(((IDataItemContainer)Container).DataItem, "Value")) %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
```

Actually this datalist contains year numbers as `Headers` as `2016, 2015`.

**Binding as**

```
 dlYearlys.DataSource = ds;
 dlYearlys.DataBind();
```

On the `ItemDataBound` I'm styling the values of totals as

```
protected void dlYearlyTotals_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
               int i = e.Item.ItemIndex;

            if (val != ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblValue")).Text)
                e.Item.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

On clicking the headers I'm displaying the another datalist values.

```
        protected void Year_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
            BindAnotherDataList((Convert.ToInt16(btn.Text)));
        }
```

This causing the page to refresh and the year values where I'm changing the colour as `red` is no more being displayed.

So how can I make dlYears `Datalist` control not to refresh and retain their colour on clicking of headers

**Page Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
          BinddlYear();
          // Binding Some other controls
      }
  }
```

Comment: What should happen exactly when you click on header link buttons?

Comment: I don't my `dlYears` datalist to refresh and loose the styles that I have done on the `ItemDataBound` when I click the headers

Comment: Can you post your page load code here?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri I have edited with page load, check it once

Comment: Your code looks correct, is it possible if you can show me your issue?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri I have no issue with bindings or anything with my existing code. On page load while I'm binding dlYears on the databound I'm styling it based on some logic. When I click on headers I'm not calling the BinddlYear() since it is posting back and I'm not binding this is leading to loose my styles. So I don't want my dlYear Datalist to refresh for the click events. I want to know how can I achieve this without calling BinddlYear() method